# Apparently MOBAC is not generating MBTiles correctly

Tags: mbtiles, mobile-atlas-creator

I am trying to generate MBTiles with MOBAC, to be used in an offline map Android application (trying to use OSMDroid).

Now I generate the atlas, but something goes wrong because I get the error

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: images (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT tile_data FROM images LIMIT 0,1

This is my MOBAC setup:

[image]

Comment: Where do you get the error? I have never had problems making mbtiles in mobac

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe Hi Devdatta when I try to open the file in my application I get the error, additionally if I try to visualize the map with MapTiler no image is shown, and if I open the file with as SQLite it seems that there are no images tables

Comment: That's very strange. Have you tried your application with a known good mbtiles file?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe actually yes, with tiles created with MapTiler it works :-(((

Answer (score 1):

You say that you are getting the error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: images (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT tile_data FROM images LIMIT 0,1

You are getting this error, because you are trying to query a table called `images`. The [Mbtiles spec](https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-spec) does not mention this table at all.

According to the MbTiles spec, the Mbtiles database has two tables: `metadata` and `tiles`. It is the later table which contains the images for the tile.

This table is created with the following SQL command:
`CREATE TABLE tiles (zoom_level integer, tile_column integer, tile_row integer, tile_data blob);`

Your problem is due to querying for a table which is not mentioned in the specifications. I'll suggest that you have a look at the code of your application, and query the correct table.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the extension .mbtiles .sqlite and open with firefox sqlite manager and launched this Requette :

```
CREATE TABLE images as
SELECT ROWID, "tile_data", tile_row as "tile_id"
FROM "tiles"
ORDER BY ROWID
```